# Why is it logging the wrong item?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture keystrokes of users, then put it in `localStorage`. But the last function `test()` is not working properly. It is logging `data2` instead of `data5`. After I reload and the script is loaded again, it is loading `data5`. But I wan't to instantly log `data5`. Maybe someone knows why!

```
window.onload = function () { // CHECK JQUERY EXISTENCE
  if (window.jQuery) {
    abc();
  } else {
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = abc;
    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
};
function abc() { // CAPTURE KEYSTROKES
  test = "";
  test2 = "";
  test3 = "";
  test4 = "";
  check = localStorage.getItem("test");
  check2 = localStorage.getItem("test2");
  check3 = localStorage.getItem("test3");
  check4 = localStorage.getItem("test4");
  if (check == null) { // EXECUTE IF CHECK (HOLDING TEST VALUE) IS EMPTY
  data = "";
  $(document).keypress(function (e) {
    data += e.key;
    localStorage.setItem("test", data);
  });
} else if (check2 == null){ // EXECUTE IF CHECK2 (HOLDING TEST2 VALUE) IS EMPTY
  data2 = localStorage.getItem("test");
  $(document).keypress(function (e) {
    data2 += e.key;
    localStorage.setItem("test2", data2);
  });
} else if (check3 == null){ // EXECUTE IF CHECK3 (HOLDING TEST3 VALUE) IS EMPTY
  data3 = localStorage.getItem("test2");
  $(document).keypress(function (e) {
    data3 += e.key;
    localStorage.setItem("test3", data3);
});
} else if (check4 == null){ // EXECUTE IF CHECK4 (HOLDING TEST4 VALUE) IS EMPTY
  data4 = localStorage.getItem("test3");
  $(document).keypress(function (e) {
    data4 += e.key;
    localStorage.setItem("test4", data4);
    data5 = localStorage.getItem("test4");
});
}
}
function test() { // VALIDATE lOCALSTORAGE ITEMS FOR CONTEXT
data2 = localStorage.getItem("test");
data3 = localStorage.getItem("test2");
data4 = localStorage.getItem("test3");
data5 = localStorage.getItem("test4");
if (data2 || data3 || data4 || data5 != null) {
  if (data2 != null && data3 && data4 && data5 == null) {
    console.log(data2);
  } else if (data3 != null && data4 && data5 == null) {
    console.log(data3);
  } else if (data4 != null && data5 == null) {
    console.log(data4);
  } else if (data5 != null) {
    console.log(data5); // HITS WHEN RELOADED
  }
} else {
  return;
}
}
test();
```

Comment: Could you explain the intention behind the series of `if` statements in this code?

Comment: @Light When page is being reloaded i have to create new local storage item. If i use the same item i am overwriting it..

Comment: `localStorage` stores strings. Strings can be checked for existence simply by doing `if(string)`. There's no need for explicit `string != null` tests.

Comment: Please explain the larger problem you are trying to solve. Why do you need to create a new item if an item already exists and how many items do you intend to be able to create? The amount of `if/then` in your example with non-descript variable names makes is really tough to know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Scott Marcus i have to create a new item if it already exists, because when i use the same item it's getting overwritten. And the whole code works except the last function test() which should return data5 in console log instead of data2. It's returning data5 when i reloaded the site, but i want to INSTANTLY log data5. It's necessary for the next function..

Comment: Yes, you've already stated all that. Please address the specific questions I asked in my last comment. Why do you need a new item if one already exists? How many items can there be? What is the larger problem you are trying to solve? What do these items represent?

Comment: @Scott Marcus There can be unlimited items, but i just need four for security purposes. The items represent the captured keystrokes. They should then be validated, if they contain context, and the one which is containing context, but is the least one, should be used for the next function..

Comment: You don't need to be creating new storage items for each keystroke and therefore your code can be MUCH simpler. Just go ahead an overwrite the last item, but make the new item the concatenation of the last item and the new item. Then you can extract this string of characters and split them into an array to examine each.

Comment: @Scott Marcus i just readjusted the code, are you talking about something likes this: https://jsfiddle.net/wjfdgc8v/1/

Comment: That's still overkill. I'll post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution is much simpler than your approach. 2 simple lines of code will do it.** Upon each keystroke, append that key to your `localStorage` value.

The following won't work here in Stack Overflow because of sandboxing, but a working example can be seen at [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksrv53wq/).

Also, note that `keypress` is a deprecated event and doesn't fire for non-printable characters. You should use `keydown` instead.

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(event){
  // This code will concatenate the last key pressed with a string
  // of characters already present in localStorage. If nothing
  // is in localStorage, then this code will create a fresh string.
  let storageChars = localStorage["chars"] ? localStorage.getItem("chars") : "";
  localStorage.setItem("chars", storageChars + event.key);
 
  // Then, you can extract/examine the characters in the string in many ways,
  // like looping over the string, turning the string into an array, indexing 
  // the string, etc.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your other logic, it looks like you only want to log `data2` if it's not null and the others are null. In that case, you want to compare each value to null in your conditional.

e.g. `data2 !== null && data3 === null && data4 === null && data5 === null`

If you don't compare to null, you're just testing for a "truthy" value (values that are not false, 0, 0n, "", null, undefined, or NaN. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Additionally, it looks like you may be trying to compare each of the values to null in this conditional: `if (data2 || data3 || data4 || data5 != null)`. If so, you'll want to code it as `if (data2 !== null || data3 !== null || data4 !== null || data5 !== null).`

You may also find this helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals#Logical_operators_AND_OR_and_NOT

Comment: Strings don't need to be explicitly tested against `null`. You can just write `if(string)`.

Comment: That's not true if they want to allow a falsey value, such as "".